# How do I bag elements of tuples in Prolog lists

Tags: list, prolog

Say I have a list:

```
Os = [(4,P1),(9,P2),(4,P3),(1,P4),(9,P5)].
```

I want to put every second element of the tuple in a bag that has the same first element like this:

```
SortedOs = [(4,[P1,P3]),(9,[P2,P5]),(1,P4)].
```

Currently I'm using bagof/3:

```
findall(
    (O,Bag),
    bagof(P,member((O,P),Os),Bag),
    SortedOs
).
```

But instead it gives me the sorted list like this:

```
SortedOs = [(1,P4),(4,[P1,P3]),(9,[P2,P5])]
```

Which means bagof/3 looks up the first element in ascending order. Is there any way I can change this to get the list I want? Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using SWI-Prolog and you can change the format of the data from tuples to [Pairs](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=pairs), (`Key-Value`) then you can use [group_pairs_by_key/2](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=group_pairs_by_key/2).

Note that for `group_pairs_by_key/2` to work correctly the input list must be sorted.

Code

```
example(Pairs0,Result) :-
    sort(Pairs0,Pairs1),
    group_pairs_by_key(Pairs1,Result).
```

Example usage

```
?- Pairs = [4-P1,9-P2,4-P3,1-P4,9-P5],example(Pairs,Result).
Pairs = [4-P1, 9-P2, 4-P3, 1-P4, 9-P5],
Result = [1-[P4], 4-[P1, P3], 9-[P2, P5]].
```

---

SWI-Prolog has a library of predicates for working with ordered sets (sorted list). [ordsets.pl](https://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/_SWI_/library/ordsets.pl) -- Ordered set manipulation

Here is a variation that checks if the input is an ordered set and skips the sorting if it is an ordered set.

```
example(List,Result) :-
    (
        is_ordset(List)
    ->
        Order_set = List
    ;
        list_to_ord_set(List,Order_set)
    ),
    group_pairs_by_key(Order_set,Result).
```

Example usage

```
?- List = [1-P4, 4-P1, 4-P3, 9-P2, 9-P5],example(List,Result).
List = [1-P4, 4-P1, 4-P3, 9-P2, 9-P5],
Result = [1-[P4], 4-[P1, P3], 9-[P2, P5]].

?- List = [4-P1,9-P2,4-P3,1-P4,9-P5],example(List,Result).
List = [4-P1, 9-P2, 4-P3, 1-P4, 9-P5],
Result = [1-[P4], 4-[P1, P3], 9-[P2, P5]].
```

Note: Ordered Sets remove duplicates so using list_to_ord_set/2 instead of sort/2 will remove duplicates.

```
?- List = [4-P1,4-P1,9-P2,4-P3,1-P4,9-P5],example(List,Result).
List = [4-P1, 4-P1, 9-P2, 4-P3, 1-P4, 9-P5],
Result = [1-[P4], 4-[P1, P3], 9-[P2, P5]].
```

---

group_pairs_by_key/2 ([source code](https://github.com/SWI-Prolog/swipl-devel/blob/909fde0e9e66a011bb1e2e22c484e2a3edaf9426/library/pairs.pl#L109-L150))

Comment: the group_pairs_by_key/2 gives the same results as the bagof/3 I'm using, but I don't want the keys to be ordered. Like if the key 4 appears before 1 then the result should have 4 in front of 1. Is there any way I can do that? Or I suppose I can try to first sort the List so that every pair with the same key follows after the first appearing key then use the group_pairs_by_key/2 to group them. But is there any other way?

Comment: Sorry but the output in the answer is not really what I'm looking for. The output keys are in ascending order but in the original list 4 goes before 9 then 1, so the order of the keys should be [4-[...], 9-[...], 1-[...]]. But I don't know how to achieve this.

Comment: I'm using a predicate group_keys/3 that sorts the list like this: `group_keys(Keys,Pairs,SortedPairs):-
    findall(
        K-P,
        (member(K,Keys),member(K-P,Pairs)),
        SortedPairs
    ).` which puts pairs with the same keys together then use the group_pairs_by_key/2 to group them which gives the result I want. Thanks for your help!